# How to detect if players alter game files and stop them from entering the game server

Tags: java, data

as the question says.

how can i check if a player modifies a file such as maps or spells in my rpg games that will be located as "/cache/spells", "/cache/maps" or "/cache/entities" and you get the point.

all the files are going to be written in .xml if that matters and the game will be an online game made in java. not a browser game btw

Comment: Once you start thinking like this, you've already lost the battle.  Any countermeasures against modification of the game client must also exist in the client.  You can make things more difficult for malicious agents, but a determined adversary will eventually prevail.  A smarter approach is to design the game game such that access to or modification of client data yields no advantage to the player (or as small an advantage as possible).

Comment: so would it be a good/smarter idea to hold spells, maps, and entity information in a database? and leave the client with only sprites?

Comment: @AngelFlores - It's worse than that.  They don't even necessarily have to modify the files, they can just write some other program to send their own packets of data (encrypting the data from your own program won't help much, cause you have to give them the encryption key).  If you want to prevent something being used in a cheat, you **MUST** validate it on the server.  Period.  (Or, well, there are 3rd party solutions that farm it out to multiple other clients, but that has its own issues)  The client should have most of the data to prevent bottlenecks, and allow prediction of outcomes.

Comment: So how should I go about validating it with the server exactly? I'm not sure on how to go about it

Comment: All we know about your game is that it has spells, maps, and entities, and is played online.  That could describe probably at least one out of every three or four games made in the last few years, so it's hard to give any specific advice.  These types of decisions rarely are black and white.

Comment: Basically it's an rpg game and I will have a database for player important files and all others resources will be saved with the client and I will make a server for players to connect to and such

Answer (score 0):

The client can use the files to reduce network latency but everything must be confirmed by the server.

For example, if the client's map has been modified to remove a wall and the client tells the server "I move from Point A to Point B" on the other side of the wall that has been removed, the server rejects the move and sends back a packet "you're at Point A".

The modified client will see itself starting to walk through the (deleted) wall and pop back to its original position just before the wall.

Every other clients will only see the confirmed moves from the server and won't see the modified client going through the wall.

Same applies for spell costs and effects.

Server has to confirm and will resynchronize everything, canceling out any client-side modifications.

The client can spawn a fireball graphic locally but the damage to the enemy will only occur once the server confirms it and the amount is decided by the server, not the client.

Essentially, you do not need to detect client-side modifications as they are rendered inconsequential and will cause more trouble for the attempted cheat than anyone else.